# Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'Graneya'. Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'

Tags: c#, sql, syntax, combobox

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll
>
> Additional information: Incorrect syntax near 'Graneya'.

Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')'.

When I executed my program it gives me such error;

This is my code:

```
private void btnKaydet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    StringBuilder name = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (Control cont in this.grpbxIstenenAnalizler.Controls) {
        if (cont is CheckBox && ((CheckBox)cont).Checked == true) {
            name.Append(((CheckBox)cont).Text.ToString() + " ");
        }
    }
    sqlcon.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_NUMUNEKAYITDEFTERI(NUMUNEADI, NUMUNEGONDEREN) VALUES('" + cmbxNumuneCinsi.Text + "'" + cmbxGonderen.Text + "')", sqlcon);
    sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sqlcon.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Kayıt OK");
}
```

Please advise

Comment: What are the value of `cmbxNumuneCinsi.Text` and  `cmbxGonderen.Text`? 
You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) by the way. This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Please show formatted sql query

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_NUMUNEKAYITDEFTERI(NUMUNEADI, NUMUNEGONDEREN) VALUES('" + cmbxNumuneCinsi.Text + "'" + cmbxGonderen.Text + "')", sqlcon);
```

to

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO TBL_NUMUNEKAYITDEFTERI(NUMUNEADI, NUMUNEGONDEREN) VALUES('" + cmbxNumuneCinsi.Text + "','" + cmbxGonderen.Text + "')", sqlcon);
```

Note

```
VALUES('" + cmbxNumuneCinsi.Text + "','" + cmbxGonderen.Text + "')"
```

Also, to avoid [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should use [parameterized queries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx), rather than string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed a comma that's why your values part will be only one character since you concatenate them.

```
('" + cmbxNumuneCinsi.Text + "'" + cmbxGonderen.Text + "')"
```

should be

```
('" + cmbxNumuneCinsi.Text + "', '" + cmbxGonderen.Text + "')"
```

#### But more important;

You should always use [parameterized queries](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/). This kind of string concatenations are open for [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Also use [`using` statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` auto instead of calling `.Close()` or `.Dispose()` methods manually.

I assume your columns are `nvarchar`, you can use;

```
using(var sqlcon = new SqlConnection(conString))
using(var sqlcmd = sqlcon.CreateCommand())
{
   sqlcmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO TBL_NUMUNEKAYITDEFTERI(NUMUNEADI, NUMUNEGONDEREN) VALUES(@ad, @gonderen)";
   sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@ad", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cmbxNumuneCinsi.Text;
   sqlcmd.Parameters.Add("@gonderen", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = cmbxGonderen.Text;

   sqlcon.Open();
   sqlcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use parameters to reduce errors.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
            "INSERT INTO TBL_NUMUNEKAYITDEFTERI(NUMUNEADI, NUMUNEGONDEREN) VALUES(@numuneCinsi, @numunegonderen)", sqlcon);

cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numuneCinsi", "firstValue"));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@numunegonderen", "secondValue"));
```